# Issue with package workmanager flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-workmanager

I have some problem when use package workmanager. Here is error:
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unhandledMethod("registerPeriodicTask") error, Unhandled method registerPeriodicTask, null, null)

How to solve this problem ???

Comment: try `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` in terminal

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when there is a mismatch between the expected method or configuration and whats actually implemented or configd in code.

**Some steps that can help your problem get resolved:**

1. Update the package by running `flutter pub upgrade workmanager`
2. Check configuration
3. Permission: Ensure that flutter has necessary permissions to execute background tasks
4. Clen and rebuild you flutter by following commands. `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and `flutter run`
5. Check for typos and imports
6. Check for platform specific code

The `workmanager` package is subject to updates and changes so refer to the package's documentation.

Now,
In the `project.pbxproj` filelocate the system capabilities section that would look like this

`/* Begin PBXProject section */`

`...`

`/* End PBXProject section */`

Here you can add system capabilities like you want to enable the background fetch capability then you would add something like this:

```
SystemCapabilities = {
   com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
      enabled = 1;
      items = (
         {
            enabled = 1;
            value = backgroundFetch;
         },
      );
   };
};
```

now modify the `com.apple.BackgroundModes` key to match the specific capability you want to enable or say configure. Configure in Xcode and Build and Run again!

Thanks

Comment: I think error in permission as you mention. I don't understand how to set up SystemCapabilities in project.pbxproj file. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/blob/main/IOS_SETUP.md. Help me bro :))))

Comment: Okay I'm modifying my answer for those